# To GAS Support Team. Are there any plans to introduce code profiler?

Tags: google-apps-script

The question is in the title. At least it will be a very handy feature to have a function returning a millisecond counter (similar to the Windows `GetTickCount` function) to estimate which code the most slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please raise requests for features like this in the [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). This will help us keep track of the demand for different feature requests.

Comment: Submitted a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1590).